# node.js (express framework): require and post

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

app.js:

```
var app = express();

require('./other_file.js')(app);
```

other_file.js:

```
app.post('/test', function(req, res) {
    console.log(true);
});
```

result: app is not defined.

How to use express methods in require file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the code you've posted the entirety of `other_file.js`? If so, you'll need to export a function that takes `app` as an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`other_file.js` should be something like that:

```
 module.exports = function(app) {
   app.post('/test', function(req, res) {
      console.log(true);
   });
 }
```

Longer story: 
when you `require()` a file you get back an object (the `exports` object). If you want to get back a function you need to make your function replace the exports object. To achieve that you need to assign your function to `module.exports`

Answer (score 1):

You have to specifically **export** the member you want to expose with a require.

`other_file.js` should look like this

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.post('/test', function(req, res) {
    console.log(true);
  });
}
```

where `module.exports` is the member that is returned when the file is used with a `require()` statement.

Node itself borrows from [**the CommonJS module spec**](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1).